# google django "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine

I am trying use Google app engine to deploy my Django and I followed the steps until "Run the Django migrations to set up your models:"

When I type `python manage.py makemigrations` and run, it just reports cannot connect.

I do not know why I cannot connect to this port.  I have closed my firewall and the IP address is 127.0.0.1.  Pymysql is installed already but still cannot connect.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000002ADF1FA38C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard_python37\django\env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 582, in connect
    **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] 無法連線，因為目標電腦拒絕連線。

pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([WinError 10061] 無法連線，因為目標電腦拒絕連線。)")


  File "C:\Users\USER\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard_python37\django\env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 629, in connect
    raise exc
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([WinError 10061] 無法連線，因為目標電腦拒絕連線。)")
```

Comment: You say you're trying to deploy to App Engine, but your app appears to be running in Windows and is attempting to connect to MySQL on your local machine. Check your `DATABASES` setting in `settings.py` and make sure it has the right connection information; you can connect to Google Cloud SQL from your local machine if you have it set up for that, but you won't be able to connect to your local database instance from App Engine (you technically might be able to set that up, but you would not want to).

Comment: hi you good
in google teach lesson it says
""cloud_sql_proxy""
and i open and run it

2018/10/15 12:18:00 Using gcloud's active project: [trytrysee-c6607]
2018/10/15 12:18:02 errors parsing config:
        invalid "trytrysee-c6607:asia-east1:dataforman": unsupported network: unix
2018/10/15 12:18:02 Ready for new connections

it appear like this so it should be ok
and i replace every DATABASES in the settings.py
so i don't know why

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure your setting file is filled with the correct db conf:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
'NAME': <db_name>,
'USER': <db_username>,
'PASSWORD': <db_password>,
'HOST': 127.0.0.1,
'PORT': 5433,
```

Then start a proxy connection following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy)

My connection command is:

`./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<instance_connection_name>=tcp:5433 -credential_file=<your_credential_file_path>`

I set all connection's port to 5433 in my confs because my local postgres db is already listening on the 5432 port.